# Как скопировать строку без последнего символа

Tags: c++, строки, c++14

Есть строка: `std::string S = "a/b/c/d/"`

И есть функция: `func(std::string G)`

Вопрос: как передать `S` в `func` на место `G`без последнего символа, например `/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать `erase` - не самая удачная идея, потому что при этом вы меняете саму исходную строку, что вряд ли входит в ваши планы...

Я бы использовал [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) -

```
foo(s.substr(0,s.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну у класса string из стандартной библиотеки есть метод erase, который удаляет символы с заданной позиции и до конца. Есть и другие полезные методы. Почитай документацию. Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(std::string G);

int main()
{
    std::string str = "a/b/c/d/";
    foo(str.erase(7));
    return 0;
}

void foo(std::string G) {
    std::cout << G << std::endl;
}
```